# OpenCV (insufficient memory in function cvAlloc)

Tags: c++, opencv

I made my simulation but I am faced with a problem. I'm getting images 640 x 480 in a video. But when it arrives at about 1600 frames or more I am faced with "insufficient memory (out of memory) in function cvAlloc". I released all the images and my RAM (mem storage) won't go over 28 MB. What should I do ?

Comment: You should definitely post the code you are using, as guessing won't help anyone.

Comment: Each frame is around 1 MB. 1600 frames is around 1.6 GB. If this is a 32 bit OS then maybe you really are running out of (virtual) memory ?

Comment: "I'm getting images..." OK, and then what are you **doing with them**?

Comment: How do you know that your RAM usage does not exceed 28MB?

Comment: perhaps you are not reusing nor releasing all the previous frames...

Comment: I think Paul is right, Each frame will take around(640*480*3=921mgb) and after 1600 frames it will crash, but can some one tell me how can I keep in the RAM one image at a time.P.S In my code I'm trying to find eyes using blob detection and also a face detection if you think I should post my code as well let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your RAM usage?

Have a look at [OpenCV Memory Management](http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/opencv-memory-management/). It lists some common techniques to fix memory leaks.

Comment: I think Paul is right, Each frame will take around(640*480*3=921mgb) and after 1600 frames it will crash, but can some one tell me how can I keep in the RAM one image at a time.P.S In my code I'm trying to find eyes using blob detection and also a face detection if you think I should post my code as well let me know

Comment: Keep releasing all images after you're done using them in one iteration. That should work.