# OpenCV refusing to allocate memory even though there is enough space

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV insufficient memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564966/opencv-insufficient-memory)

I have a program that I am running for several iterations.  It works fine on the first few, but as it gets through them it crashes due to an OpenCV insufficient memory error.  Problem is, there is plenty of available memory!  I am not near the RAM limits, nor the disk space limits.

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
// ftrs is a vector of MyFeature objects.
// it has 289600 elements
// FEATURE_DIMENSIONALITY is 58
cv::Mat data_pts(ftrs.size(), FEATURE_DIMENSIONALITY, CV_32FC1);
```

And here is the error:

> OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 70662404 bytes)
>   in unknown function, file
>   ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52

So, this is a very peculiar error.  What else might be causing this?  To reiterate, there is absolutely enough RAM available at that time point, and there is enough disk space present.  Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Or even [OpenCV (insufficient memory in function cvAlloc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335988/opencv-insufficient-memory-in-function-cvalloc)

Answer (score 3):

If your process is a 32-bit process the amount of available ram is actually not that much just a few Gigabytes actually. So you can actually be hitting the limit of a 32-bit process. Try checking how much memory you are using when the error occurs.